# Translating Ruby to Java : Does Java have a construct that is close to the Ruby switch statement

Tags: java, ruby, switch-statement

I'm trying to translate what the code I have, in Ruby, to Java.

So far I have been unable to come across a switch statement-type construct in Java that will let me call methods in the cases.

Does anyone have any suggestions for a replacement construct that performs similar to the code below.

```
def move_validator
    message = nil

    case 
    when out_of_bounds?(@x_dest, @y_dest) == true
      message = "You cannot move off the board"

    when no_checker_at_origin? == true
      message = "There is no checker to move in requested location"

    when trying_to_move_opponents_checker? == true 
      message = "You cannot move an opponents checker"  

    when trying_to_move_more_than_one_space_and_not_jumping? == true
      message = "You cannot move more than one space if not jumping"

    when attempted_non_diagonal_move? == true
      message = "You can only move a checker diagonally"

    when attempted_move_to_occupied_square? == true
      message = "You cannot move to an occupied square"

    when non_king_moving_backwards? == true
      message = "A non-king checker cannot move backwards"

    when attempted_jump_of_empty_space? == true  
      message = "You cannot jump an empty space"

    when attempted_jump_of_own_checker? == true
      message = "You cannot jump a checker of your own color"

    when jump_available_and_not_taken? == true
      message = "You must jump if a jump is available"  

    else
      move
      if jumping_move?
        message = "jumping move"
        remove_jumped_checker
      end
      king_checkers_if_necessary
    end
    message
  end
```

Thanks.

Comment: @Perception Yeah, I thought of that, but that would be a fairly brute force, inelegant solution. I was wondering if I could do better.

Comment: @steve_gallagher the compiler translates the switch into an optimized if/else construct anyway.

Comment: @Woot4Moo My concern is, chiefly, readability. I like how the statements read in Ruby but a huge if/else block would just be ugly.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Trolling?... Not sure where you get that from in my question. I think your comment misses the point of the question. I'm looking for a substitute for the switch construct in Java that parallels the ability of the case statement in Ruby. It's not important where the terms originate.

Comment: @steenslag Thank you. Not sure how I missed that.

Comment: Why are you translating Ruby to Java in the first place (there's always JRuby and/or RJB...)?

Comment: My point was that, in light of the context and history, it seems bizarre to phrase the question as is.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel I understand, and I take from your comment that, when dealing with a community of extremely knowledgeable people, I should take care to ensure the precision of my question's phrasing. Where I took issue with your comment is the labeling of my question as "trolling". In a forum like this, I can't think of a worse label to be affixed with, and, as a new user, it could be especially damaging.

Comment: @Marnen Laibow-Koser The program this code is associated with is a project for a software engineering class that I am doing with a team. I like Ruby, so I did the initial version of my part of the code in Ruby. However, my teammates insisted on doing the project in Java, so I needed to translate it.

Comment: Believe me, if I had wanted to label you a troll, I would have been very explicit about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated:

```
if(condition)  
{  
   function();  
}  
else if( condition)  
{  
   function();  
}
```

Downside is you will have to manually optimize the order in which they go.

Comment: It doesn't allow method calls in it's case statements. I need that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Just:

```
if (outOfBound(y, y)) {
    message = "...";
} else if (attemptedNonDiagonalMove()) {
    message = "...";
} else {
    ...
}
```

Or make every condition an object of your own Condition class with a test() and a getMessage() and have a List. Problem are the x, y parameters.

Comment: That's a pretty cool idea. It looks like I will have to do that to get what I want.